# Stop VSCode triggering suggestion when pressing "enter" key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I am editing JSX code in .js files, and since two days (i don't know why), **each time I press ENTER key in VS Code to add a new empty line, then VS Code display this**:

[image: This is what VS code do]

**If I press ENTER again, then VS Code add "//#endregion" in my code.**

But the point is, I don't want this, I just want to jump a line, I don't want VS Code to write this for me.

**Do you know why VS Code has this behavior now, and how I can avoid VS Code doing this ?**

**PS**: *this is my Trigger Suggest config*
[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: I guess something messed up your keymapping.
Press Ctrl+K Ctrl+S and look for "Trigger Suggest".
I could imagine the shortcut was set to Enter.

Comment: Thank you Malte. I checked my 3 Trigger Suggest actions, and they're all set to default, and key binding is not set on "ENTER" key

Comment: I can avoid this by clicking CMD + Enter, and then it add a new line, but it is still very ennoying :D

Comment: Might be a clichee, but did you try to turn the whole damn thing off and on again? :D

Comment: Nope ahah, not yet, will try in few hours ;)

Comment: After some action in key binding config, I actually needed a VS Code restart to make it work. Thank you 

Answer (score 4):

As Rajesh and Malte said, go in Key Binding preferences (Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts) and remove the key binding on "ENTER" key related to "suggestWidgetVisible" solved the problem.

But you actually have to **restart** VS Code to make this changes being took in account.

**You can also go here** if you want to keep suggestion but if you don't want them to apply on pressing "ENTER":
[image]

Settings > Text editor > Suggestions > Accept suggestion on Enter > off

Answer (score 2):

Go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

In the search bar select the Recording keys option and press Enter.

For all the results, right click and click on Remove Keybinding as shown below.

[image]

Comment: I already did that, but I actually had to restart VS Code to have my changes took in account ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to put the suggestions in user/text editor/suggestions/Editor: Accept Suggestion On Enter => smart. This way you can have both suggestions and jumping to new lines by pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

Open `settings.json` file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  => *User Settings json*). Then within curly braces `{}` put this line:

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
```

and then save the file. Now you should be able to go to new line when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.